# How to merge columns of data based on another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and would like to merge some columns based on a distinct value in another column. 
My example data:[image]

Expected outcome:
[image]

Comment: Your expected outcome is verbose CSV and is a fairly rancid way to store data in a SQL table.  Is this just a presentation thing, or do you plan to actually store this CSV?

Comment: The data is stored in the SQL table I am only using csv to provide example data.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky in SQL Server 2008 -- you should update your software!  It is at the end of its life.

The method uses XML:

```
select s.style,
       stuff( (select ',' + convert(varchar(255), curr)
               from (select t.*,
                            row_number() over (partition by t.style order by (select null)) as rowid
                     from t
                    ) t cross apply
                    (values (GPB, 1), (EUR, 2), (USD, 3), (AUD, 4)
                    ) v(curr, ord)
               where t.style = s.style
               order by rowid, ord
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as currencies
from (select distinct style from t) s;
```

The `order by` keeps all values from the same row together and orders the values by the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.Style,

    ProductIDs = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + t2.ProductIDs 
        FROM TableName t2
        WHERE t1.Style= t2.Style
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1, 2, '')
FROM TableName t1
GROUP BY t1.Style
```